# Fastest solution to compute normal

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex

A physics engine return a deformed mesh (only geometry vertices). 
I take this mesh to render the geometry (~500000 vertices).
What is the fastest solution and the least expensive to compute normal vertices every frame ?
OpenCL ? Geometry Shaders ? In a CPU thread ? Other ?

Comment: Yes but it's not expensive on geometry shader ?

Comment: @KillianDS: You want a shader to sample arbitrarily into an array of connected vertices to compute a vertex normal? I can't say that this is the most parallel-friendly activity. Sure, the inputs have one output, but vertex shaders would be terrible at it (you can't use attribute inputs at all), geometry shaders don't have a complex enough topography to do it (and they'd be no better than vertex shaders ultimately), etc. Shaders are generally meant for rendering; while they can do this, I wouldn't expect them to be the fastest thing at it.

Comment: This question cannot be answered as asked. What the "fastest solution" is will vary wildly with hardware and implementations. Not to mention that, regardless of what you're coming up with, you'll have to stream 500k+ vertices per frame. The best you can do is try out several techniques and benchmark them. That being said, are you sure your physics system can't be made to spit out normals? It must have most of the information needed to generate them when it does its deformation.

Comment: For what do you need the normals?

Comment: @KillianDS: And how do you propose to compute SMOOTH normals on geometry shader?

Comment: OP, for a start try computing it on the CPU. BEFORE searching for the "fastest" solution you should at least try doing *something* to see if it will perform well. So far it looks like you haven't even tried to compute normals using the most trivial algorithm.